# Issue with for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to get the square of prime numbers between 1:10 using for loop as below:

```r
sq_pr_no = function()
{
  sq_pr_no = c()
  for (i in 1:10)
  {
    for (p in 2:i - 1)
    {
      if (i %% p == 0)
      {
        sq_pr_no = c(sq_pr_no, i ^ 2)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm getting error as follows

> Error in if (i %% p == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: I wonder if it would help if you set out what you believe each step in your function is doing?

Comment: When `p==1` you create `i` as `2:1 - 1` what is `1` and `0`, and than you calculate `1 %% 0` what gives `NaN` what you compare `NaN == 0`, what gives `NA` what is used in `if(NA)` what gives the *Error*.

Answer (score 1):

`2:i - 1` is `(2 : i) - 1`. You want `2 : (i - 1)`. Even then, `i - 1` will be `0` on the first iteration, and `i %% 0` yields `NaN`, which causes the error you’re observing.

To fix the error, exclude the case where `p == 0`.

(`a : b` is generally a dangerous pattern when used with variables, since it automatically goes backwards if `b` < `a`.)

Your function is also not returning any value. You may be used to setting a return value by assigning to a variable with the same name as the function but R doesn’t work like this: in R, the value of a function is the value of its last expression, and `for` loops in R unfortunately do not have a value.